# Shouldn't [xss] and [cross-site] be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

The description for [xss](/questions/tagged/xss) reads:

> Cross-Site Scripting attacks are a type of injection problem, in which malicious scripts are injected into the otherwise benign and trusted web sites. Cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks occur when an attacker ...

and that of [cross-site](/questions/tagged/cross-site) reads:

> Cross-site scripting (XSS) is a type of computer security
>   vulnerability typically found in Web applications.

Shouldn't the two tags be synonyms?  Maybe [cross-site](/questions/tagged/cross-site) can be a synonym for [xss](/questions/tagged/xss).

Currently there are 1834 questions tagged [xss](/questions/tagged/xss) and 87 tagged [cross-site](/questions/tagged/cross-site).

---

**UPDATE:**  The [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202838/218079) below mentions that [cross-site](/questions/tagged/cross-site) often refers to legitimate cross-site functionality.  I'm not quite sure.  The questions cited as examples appear to be incorrectly tagged as [cross-site](/questions/tagged/cross-site).  Those seem more appropriate to be tagged [cross-domain](/questions/tagged/cross-domain) (aka [cross-origin](/questions/tagged/cross-origin)).

Comment: synonym would be better than a merge. If the two words are sufficiently different then a synonym is more suitable. Merge works better for combining plural and singular together.

Comment: @JonW I agree.  I realized that while I was writing the question which is why I suggested that towards the end.

Answer (score 7):

No, they should not. They are not synonyms, although they are related, and they often misused.

[xss](/questions/tagged/xss) mostly refers to the security vulnerability known as "cross-site scripting."

[cross-site](/questions/tagged/cross-site) often refers to legitimate cross-site functionality. Look at the questions:

- [How to fix cross-site origin policy for server and web-site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385438/how-to-fix-cross-site-origin-policy-for-server-and-web-site)
- [Cross site calls without JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868336/cross-site-calls-without-jsonp)

The only problem that needs fixing is the description of [cross-site](/questions/tagged/cross-site).

Comment: +1, and please do so!

Comment: I believe that the examples you've cited are tagged somewhat incorrectly, those probably needed to be tagged `cross-domain` aka `cross-origin`.

Comment: @devnull: I guess it's ambiguous, but if [tag:cross-site] would be merged into [tag:xss], that would make tags for these questions completely wrong.

Comment: @vartec As I mentioned earlier, it seems to me that some of the questions tagged [cross-site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-site) that you're referring to should have rather been tagged [cross-domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-domain).